# What is OracleXEUniv.exe functionality?

Tags: oracle

A have some step by step description where downloading of OracleXEUniv.exe is one step. 
But I cannot find what is it for? What is functionality of this file?

Than you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OracleXE is the free version of Oracle's main database product. The "Universal" simply means it will install using the Universal character set instead of the Western European character set.

Answer (score 1):

> Oracle Database Express Edition (Oracle Database XE) is an
>   entry-level, small-footprint database based on the Oracle Database. 
>   It's free to develop, deploy, and distribute; fast to download; and
>   simple to administer.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/express-edition/overview/index.html